# Mapping the array of nested arrays/objects

Tags: arrays, dictionary, object, return, mapping

This is how my Array looks like. It contains objects which contain a few values. First value is again an array which contains config for that array item. The other values are: date, id, name, totalConfigPrice, waitingTime. Than, below, there are totalPrice, totalQuantity, totalWaitingTime that sum the possibly more than one objects in main array.

```
[
    {
        "configs": [
            {
                "config": {
                    "brakes": {
                        "name": "Brakes",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "color": {
                        "name": "Color",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "exhaust": {
                        "name": "Exhaust",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "logo": {
                        "name": "Logo",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "power": {
                        "name": "Power",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "seat": {
                        "name": "Seat",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "suspension": {
                        "name": "Suspension",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "wheel": {
                        "name": "Wheel",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    },
                    "windshield": {
                        "name": "Windshield",
                        "price": 0,
                        "value": "none",
                        "waitingTime": 0
                    }
                },
                "date": "04/10/2022, 14:22:53",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Dragon",
                "totalConfigPrice": 0,
                "waitingTime": 0
            }
        ],
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "totalQuantity": 1,
        "waitingTime": 0
    }
]
```

This is how my mapping looks like:

```
return orders.map((item) => {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          {item.configs.forEach((configData) => {
            Object.keys(configData.config).map((configItem) => {
              return (
                <li>
                  <span>{configData.config[configItem].name}</span>
                  <span>{configData.config[configItem].price}</span>
                  <span>{configData.config[configItem].value}</span>
                  <span>{configData.config[configItem].waitingTime}</span>
                </li>
              );
            });
            <>
              <span>{configData.date}</span>
              <h1>{configData.name}</h1>
              <span>{configData.totalConfigPrice}</span>
              <span>{configData.waitingTime}</span>
            </>;
          })}
        </li>

        <span>{item.totalPrice}</span>
        <span>{item.totalQuantity}</span>
        <span>{item.waitingTime}</span>
      </ul>
    );
  });
};
```

I do get only the last three "span"s returned on my page (item.totalPrice, item.TotalQuantity, item.waitingTime).

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you expecting the `forEach` to return a value?

Comment: Actually I changed it to map. That was initial mistake I made... In the end I got it solved as well...

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my question:

```
return orders.map((item) => {
    return (
      <ul className={classes.orders} key={item.cartId}>
        <li className={classes["order-item"]}>
          {item.configs.map((configData) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className={classes["order-item-top"]} key={configData.id}>
                  <h2>"{configData.name}"</h2>
                  <div>
                    <span>
                      <em>
                        Ordered on:<strong> {configData.date}</strong>
                      </em>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <ul className={classes["item-config-list"]} key={configData.id}>
                  {Object.keys(configData.config).map((configItem) => {
                    return (
                      <li className={classes["item-config"]} key={configItem}>
                        <h4>{configData.config[configItem].name}</h4>
                        <div>
                          <span>
                            Price: {configData.config[configItem].price}
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <span>
                            Value: {configData.config[configItem].value}
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <span>
                            Waiting Time:{" "}
                            {configData.config[configItem].waitingTime}
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </li>
        <div className={classes["order-summary"]}>
          <span>
            <strong>Total Bikes in Order: {item.totalQuantity}</strong>
          </span>
          <span>
            <strong>Total Order Price: {item.totalPrice}</strong>
          </span>
          <span>
            <strong>Total Order Waiting Time: {item.waitingTime}</strong>
          </span>
        </div>
      </ul>
    );
  });
};
```